# Is it possible to order an R contingency table by rowSums

Tags: r, contingency

I have created a contingency table with several variables/cols by 510 categories/factors. I want to have factors ordered descending based on the sum of all variables/cols.

Tried converting table back to DF and rowSums but no luck.
Not sure if possible to sort while using table function?

```
DF structure
'data.frame':   2210 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Paddock_ID: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year      : num  2010 2011 2011 2012 2012 ...
 $ LandUse   : chr  "Wheat" "Wheat" "Wheat" "Wheat" ...
 $ LUT       : chr  "Cer" "Cer" "Cer" "Cer" ...
 $ LUG       : chr  "Wheat" "Wheat" "Wheat" "Wheat" ...
 $ Tmix      : Factor w/ 6 levels "6","5","4","3",..: 6 5 6 4 6 5 4 5 6 6 
...
 $ combo     : Factor w/ 510 levels "","GLYPHOSATE",..: 416 6 59 119 30 
22 510 2 2 509

my table
a <- table(DF$"combo", DF$"LUG")
```

I get table ok but would like to have it ordered based on sum of all variables/columns i.e. Glyphosate = 124, then clethodim = 69, then paraquat = 53 ... descending for all 510 categories (rows).

```
                               Barley Canola Lupin Other Pasture Wheat

GLYPHOSATE                             4     46     6     5      23    40
TRALKOXYDIM                            0      0     0     0       0     8
MCPA; GLYPHOSATE; METSULFURON          0      0     0     0       0     1
METSULFURON                            1      0     0     0       0     1
BUTROXYDIM; METSULFURON                1      0     0     0       0     0
GLYPHOSATE; METSULFURON; PYRAFLUFEN    0      0     0     0       0     1
PARAQUAT                               2      7     7     2      28     7
CLETHODIM                              0     41    15     3       0     0
```

Comment: Suppose you have stored the contingency table as `cm`. Then, what happens if you do `cm[order(rowSums(cm)),]`?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, you would have to specify ```decreasing = T``` for the correct solution.

Comment: @RStats yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Using an example dataset:

```
grades <- c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,3)
credits <- c(4,4,4,8,4,4,8,4,4,4,8,4,4)
df <- cbind(grades, credits)
```

You can find the rowsums using `rowSums()`.

One possible solution would be to create another column for rowsums and then sort with `decreasing = T`.

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$sum <- rowSums(df)
df <- df[order(df[,3], decreasing = T),]
```

Comment: Creating another column is unnecessary.

Comment: Depending on whether or not u are interested in the actual sum. I´d assume when one is sorting depending on a value, they might be interested in keeping the information.

Comment: You can also put `order(df[,3])` in `rev()` for less typing.

Comment: @gersht I think `rev` will be less efficient than `decreasing = T`. Check description section of `?rev`.

Comment: I have tried the rowSums option and decreasing =T but while the table shows as 6 cols in consol the structure is a list of 2 cols, shown below, so these don't work work                             
 'table' int [1:507, 1:6] 0 0 5 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:507] "" "CLOPYRALID" "GLYPHOSATE" 
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "Barley" "Canola" …                                                                 Think I just need to rearrange this list so my crops are in separate cols then do rowsums and then decreasing but have tried levels and group_by with no luck?

Comment: Hi I, calculated Totals of Rows and placed new col at end of table using      my_table <- cbind(my_table, Total = rowSums(my_table)). I now need to sort. have used this code newdata <- my_table[order(my_table$Total),]      but get error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" any tips please??